# Как сравнить число с каждым элементом массива

Tags: массивы

> Есть массив {15,15,15,16,17,19,19,23}, нужно вывести пропущенные
>   числа (18,20,21,22)

Как это сделать? 
Сломал голову уже)

Comment: Если есть массив полный, то сравнивать два массива. Либо взять максимальный элемент и от 0 до MAX сравнивать в цикле. Если есть такое число, то пропустить, если нет, то вывести.

Comment: Покажите попытки ломания головы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < mass.length - 1; i++){

    int num = mass[i + 1] - mass[i];

    if(num > 1){

        for(int j = 1; j < num; j++){

              sout(mass[i] + j);

       }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь)

Comment: отметь как ответ)

Comment: такое решение требует чтобы массив был отсортирован, но в вопросе об этом не сказано.